# Useeffect in React Native functional component not getting called

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I have the following functional component in React Native that calls another component
`<ProfileQuestionsEntryComponent questionArray={data.qDescription} />`

I have spent a few days trying to find why the useeffect is no longer getting called when I load the page.  It just says render returns null.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import {List } from 'react-native-paper';
import ProfileQuestionsEntryComponent from '../../assets/Components/ProfileQuestionsEntry'

const HomeScreen = ({ }) => {
  const [QuestionsList, setQuestionsList] = React.useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
      
      console.log("called");
        try {
 
             fetch('http://SomeAPIThatreturnsJSON/listquestions/4/1').then((response) => response.json()).then((json) => {
             setQuestionsList(json);
 
         }).catch((error) => {
             console.error(error);
         });
 
     } catch(err) {
         console.log("Error fetching data-----------", err);
     }
       
    }, []);

  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(true);
  const handlePress = () => setExpanded(!expanded);
  QuestionsList.map((data) => {
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ paddingVertical: 20 }}>
    <List.Section title="Level 1 Questions! ">
      <List.Accordion   title="This is an accordian??"        >
           <ProfileQuestionsEntryComponent questionArray={data.qDescription} /> 
      </List.Accordion>
    </List.Section>
    </ScrollView>
    </View>
    )
  });
};
 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: 30,
    marginLeft: 20, 
    marginRight: 20,
    flex: 1,
  },
  buttonView: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: 10,
  },
});
 
export default HomeScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something from your component. `QuestionsList` is empty at the first place. so your component does not return anything. You have to return something if QuestionsList is empty

```
if (QuestionsList.length === 0) return null;
```

Above your mapping stuff, just check to see if `QuestionsList` is empty then return `null`. Since you are not returning anything you get an error. You need to fix that error first then check whether `useEffect` gets call or not.

Or you can show a loading indicator if `QuestionsList` is empty.

```
if (QuestionsList.length === 0) return <p>Loading ...</p>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the QuestionsList map as well.
return QuestionsList.map( ...